# An idiom or expression to describe feeling slack

Tags: idioms, expressions

I am looking for an idiom or expression to describe feeling slack to do things (not due to physical tiredness necessarily, but it can also be because of a lack of enthusiasm and motivation). I think of using the expression 'dragging the feet'. Does it fit? Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: There are lots of word in this general area. Check out synonyms for ***lethargy, apathy, listlessness,...***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dragging one's feet" could fit your context. It tends to mean that someone *is* doing something, but they are being slow about it, or deliberately obstructive.

Other similar idioms include:

- *stringing it out* (taking longer than needed over something)
- using *delaying tactics* (deliberately causing a delay)
- playing for time (wasting time)
- giving you the run around (being evasive)

You could say someone is *apathetic* or *indifferent*. You could also say they are *procrastinating* or *delaying*.

Answer (score 1):

There's a joke form.  If you are enthusiastic you have "get up and go".  So the joke is

> My get-up-and-go got up and went...

But more normally you would idiomatically talk about "lacking motivation"

> Since the lockdown I've been finding it hard to keep up my fitness routine. I just haven't been able to find motivation, now that all the races have been cancelled or postponed.

That is more "idiomatic" than using some kind of fixed "idiom".